# Shared Preference flutter web issue

Tags: flutter-web, flutter-sharedpreference

I'm using shared_preference version 2.0.6,
as per the documentation  shared_preference version 0.5.6 by default supports web.  as show in code **1st log works fine but the 2nd log not happening** and in **future builder** showing

NoSuchMethodError: Unexpected Null Value

method not found

Receiver: null

Arguments: []

```
SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
print("checking logged in user");//1st log
String loginedInUser = prefs.getString("user");
print("logged in user" + loginedInUser);//2nd log
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found what was the problem, consider below code:

```dart
SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
String loginedInUser = prefs.getString("user"); //2nd line
```

- While using `shared_preferences` for Flutter web, getter  **key(user)** can't be null means that if stored value of **user** is null 2nd line will not return null instead it shows an error, if the **user** has some data then returns that value.
- While using `SharedPreferences` for Flutter in Android 2nd line returns null without any errors.

Comment: did you resolve the issue? In my app some values needed to have a null value, but shared_preferences in web breaks the app.